# ContactsContract.Data implicit-join columns not working?

Tags: android

Sorry if this might be a duplicate question, I've spent the evening trying to wrap my head around this, and I can't seem to find other posts that might cast some light on this as well, so I am hoping that a few more pair of eyes might spot something.

I am having this impression from the API docs for [ContactsContract.Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) that when you specify certain fields, the library does some magic and performs an implicit join for you in the background.

Doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;

private Cursor getContacts()
{
    // Run query
    Uri uri = Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            Phone.NUMBER,
            Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
            Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            Phone.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP
    };
    String selection = Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '1' AND " + Phone.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    return getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```

When this is run, it dies with a:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2
```

From the docs for [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html) it clearly states that:

```
You can use all columns defined for ContactsContract.Data as well as the following aliases.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE is your problem. That's not a column name, that's a constant that Data.MIME_TYPE is set to.  Remove it from your projection and it should be fine.